# How do I select pairs from table with distance less than x?

Tags: sql, postgresql, inner-join, self-join

In my database, I have a table of houses. Each house has a street id and a distance in meters from the start of the street.

I want to find all pairs of houses along the same street that are in a distance less than e.g. 20 meters from each other.

This is a sample table called `HOUSES`

```
house_id  street_id  distance_from_beginning
1         100        5
2         100        10
3         100        15
4         200        5
5         200        20
6         200        10
```

I am searching for an SQL statement that looks like

```
SELECT 
    h1.house_id, 
    h2.house_id, 
    abs(h1.distance_from_beginning - h2.distance_from_beginning) distance
from HOUSES h1, h2 
where h1.street_id=h2.street_id and distance < 20
```

Is this possible? What would be the correct syntax for a Postgresql database?

Comment: Look at cross join. It is a way to achieve cartesian product of two tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a self-join on the `HOUSE` table where houses are in the same street :

```
SELECT 
    h1.house_id, h2.house_id, ABS(h1.distance - h2.distance)
FROM 
    HOUSES h1
    INNER JOIN HOUSES h2 
        ON  h1.street_id = h2.street_id 
        AND h1.house_id < h2.house_id
        AND ABS(h1.distance - h2.distance) < 20
```

Tested in [this db fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/p3aApfLHCNwmsuTyYJQyKj/0).